# Using 2captcha Service got attribute error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, 2captcha

I install the 2cpatcha buy using these command `pip install 2captcha-python` but they give me these error
`TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'normal'`  is there any solution kindly recommend that

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')

time.sleep(2)
# Locate and capture the CAPTCHA element
captcha_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='_2hXzbgz7SSP0DXCyvKWcha']")
captcha_element.screenshot('captcha/captcha.png')

time.sleep(2)
# Set up 2Captcha solver
api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', '-------')
solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

try:
    # Solve CAPTCHA
    result = solver.normal('captcha/captcha.png')

# except Exception as e:
except Exception as e:
    print("2Captcha API is not working:", e)
else:
    print(result)
```